# Vuepress with base set throws 404 error on refresh

Tags: image, http-status-code-404, radix, vuepress

I have the index.md for a Vuepress site. I have the heroImage set as `heroImage: /my-image-logo.png`

in the `docs/.vuepress/config.js` I have the logo set as:

```
themeConfig: {
    logo: 'my-image-logo.png',
}
```

It loads fine initially, however, if I navigate away from the index.md page to a page in the `/guide` and then refresh the page, it fails to load with a `404` error. I'm assuming it is because I have the `base` parameter set as: `/some/sub/directory/path/` and it can't seem to find it.

Are there workarounds for this already that I'm just not seeing? i have tried adding the base to the `logo:` parameter but nothing shows up.

I should mention that the rest of the images I have been able to get to render all the time by using with `withBase` function:

`<img :src="$withBase('/aPicture.png')" alt="some picture">`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your *logo* image in the following location:
`docs/src/.vuepress/public/my-image-logo.png`

```
docs
└─ src
   ├─ .vueress
   |   ├─ public
   .   |  └─ my-image-logo.png
   .   ├─ config.js
   .   .
```

Then in `config.js` set the `logo` like this

```js
themeConfig: {
  ...
  logo: /my-image-logo.png
  ...
}
```

This solution worked for me when I added a *logo* image

### VuePress Docs

[Asset Handling/Public Files](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/assets.html#public-files)